How to position dynamically generated switches in Grid?
I'm trying to create a plasmoid for KDE Plasma 6 with toggle switches.
in the config.qml configuration file, the switches are dynamically generated in a list, this list therefore gives the order of creation of the switches.
in the main.qml file
The switches: JSON contains the model data of the switches defined in config.qml (name, switchId, isMaster, isMain, checked, ect...)
the isMaster and isMaster are 2 types of switches which are defined in switches, the isMaster controls the isMains which are below him until there is another isMaster which in turn controls the isMains which are after him.
The goal is that in main.qml I would like each time an isMaster is displayed to create a column, so if for example I have 3 isMasters and 6 isMains it will look like this:
First isMaster | Second isMaster | third isMaster
First isMain   | third isMain    | fifth isMAin
second isMain  | fourth isMAin   | sixth isMain

I do not know how to do.
Here is the main.qml:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid
import org.kde.plasma.core as PlasmaCore
import org.kde.plasma.plasma5support as Plasma5Support
import org.kde.plasma.components as PlasmaComponents3
import org.kde.kirigami as Kirigami

PlasmoidItem {
    id: root

    readonly property var switches: JSON.parse(Plasmoid.configuration.switches)
  
    preferredRepresentation: fullRepresentation

    fullRepresentation: GridLayout {
        id: fullRoot

        Repeater {
            id: switchRepeater
            model: root.switches

            delegate: RowLayout {

                PlasmaComponents3.Switch {
                    checked: modelData.defaultPosition
                    onCheckedChanged: root.toggleAction(modelData.switchId, checked)
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter
                }

                PlasmaComponents3.Label {
                    text: modelData.displayName ? modelData.name : ""
                    color: modelData.switchNameColor
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Creating a 2D grid view from a 1D list of data will be difficult. I recommend further processing your model data to structure it into a 2D array of some sort. Then instead of using a GridLayout, I'd use nested Repeaters. The outer Repeater would generate ColumnLayouts, and the inner Repeater would create RowLayouts.
